# Bootstrap Collapse Not Allowing Radio To Be Checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I have a radio in the collapse header for each collapsible section.  If I click on the header itself, the radio checks.  If I click on the radio, the collapse functions, but the radio unchecks itself.  You have to set a breakpoint in in javascript to notice it checking.

```
    $('#accordion-advfeatures .accordion-heading a').click(function(){
        if (!$(this).parent().parent().children('.accordion-body').hasClass('in')) {
           $(this).children('input').attr('checked',true);
        } else {
           $("#advancedDefault").attr('checked',true);
        }
    });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d2y6a/

Anyone have any ideas how I can get these radios to function like they should?

Comment: Some part of your code is causing a conflict. Try rewriting it.

Comment: `input`s are not supposed to be inside of `a`s. That's invalid HTML and might be at least part of the problem.

Comment: Nick, if you'd like to leave an answer I can give you the credit.